# Bought a new black toner for xerox phaser 6020, printer still says it's empty

Tags: printer

the black toner in my Xerox Phaser 6020 ran out, so I bought a new toner. I replaced it, but the printer still shows that the toner is empty.

I followed the maintenance instructions and first cleaned the LED lenses. Nothing changed.
Then, I tried refreshing the toner and cleaning the developer. However, when I try to do so through the Print Utility, I get the message "Communication with printer failed".

I'm not sure what other options are here to fix the printer issue. Could you please advise me?

Comment: Did you purchase a genuine Xerox product, or a "compatible" version to fit your printer?

Comment: @fred_dot_u Both. The third party one actually worked with magenta, but not with black. No black toner worked after that.